# C++ Decode quoted-printable encoding with GMime 3.0

Tags: c++, decode, mime, quoted-printable

I have an e-mail which is made of multiple parts, I parsed it successfully with GMime, but I can't figure out how to decode the **Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable** parts.

I saw there are automaton-like functions but I don't know how to use them.

> g_mime_encoding_init_decode()
>
> g_mime_encoding_quoted_decode_step()

Does someone know how to do this?
My input is a text file containing the message.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use those methods. All you need to do is do:

```
content = g_mime_part_get_content (part);
g_mime_data_wrapper_write_to_stream (content, output_stream);
```

At this point, `output_stream` will contain the decoded content.